# Pivot map into column in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm looking for a way to pivot a list of map in Hive into several column and insert the values depending on each key dynamically.

For example with:

```
uid  map
001  {"key1":1,"key2":2}
002  {"key1":3}
003  {"key2":4,"key3":5}
```

I want to render:

```
uid  key1  key2  key3
001    1     2
002    3
003          4     5
```

Given that I have a high number of keys, I want to be able to do so without having to specify the key in the query like

```
select uid,
       map['key1'] as key1,
       map['key2'] as key2,
       map['key3'] as key3
from my table
```

Do any of you have a solution or know if it is possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are typically out of luck if you dynamically want to place data in columns in Hive.

If you absolutely want to do this dynamically, here is what you could do with an external tool (like python):

1. Use python to determine which keys you need, and create the table with relevant keys
2. Parse each line and insert data in the relevant columns

Comment: That's what I was afraid of but I wanted to be sure. Thanks